# Full House Probability: Why is my answer incorrect?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, poker

For the probability of a full house, I did:

```
52/52 * 3/51 * 2/50 * 48/49 * 47/48  = 3/20825
```

I was off by a factor of 10 or in other words:

```
C(5,3)
```

Can anyone explain how to get this factor to me please?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You method appears to compute the probability of getting dealt three of a kind as the first three cards of a five card hand.  You appear to require that the triple come first and you seem to ignore the fact that the other two cards must be a pair.

Comment: Also, the product you write is $\frac {47}{20825}$, not what you claimed.  Perhaps you intended your last fraction to be $\frac 3{48}$?  If so, then your error was assuming the fixed order.

Comment: "Sorry I mean to write 47/48 for the last product instead of 3/48"  Why?  Shouldn't it but $\frac 3{48}$?  You need the fifth card to be the same rank as the fourth card and there are only $3$ of those.  Not $47$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assuming that the Full House, which is of the form $AAABB$ for some $A$ and $B$, is being dealt to you in that very order: i.e. that *first* you get all the three $A$'s, and *then* you get the two $B$'s. However, if the cards are being dealt to you in the order $BAABA$ you end up with the same Full House. Indeed, there are $5 \choose 3$ ways in which the three $A$'s are being dealt to you to get three $A$'s and two $B$'s.

Comment: That is not the only error.  See the comments.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig That's more likely a typo, as the OP has clearly seen that their final answer is exactly a factor of $10 = \binom 52$ too small, not a factor of approximately $1.57$ too large, which would be a lot more difficult to put your finger on

Comment: @N.F.Taussig True, but I assume that was the OP not being careful in typing the equation into the post. Having a $3$ there instead of a $47$ would not only give the answer as indicated by the OP, but would also be compatible with the OP 's thinking. The real (conceptual) error is the one I indicated.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, sorry. Yes, you caught my error. Thank you so much!